# HeapSetInformation fails on x64

Tags: c, windows, exception, winapi, heap-memory

I run my code perfectly fine in x86, but once I switch to x64 I get a read access exception from ntdll on the first parameter (the heap handle).

```
if(!HeapSetInformation((HANDLE)heap->base, HeapCompatibilityInformation, &lfrag, sizeof(lfrag)))
```

heap->base is an UINT_PTR the same size as HANDLE.

lfrag is just `ULONG lfrag = 2;`

I create a heap just previous to this call like this: `heap->base = (UINT_PTR)HeapCreate(0, 0, 0);`

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I'd like my program to be x64 compatible.

Maybe I cannot enable low fragmentation on x64? I cannot see anything about this on MSDN, though

Comment: IIRC, the low fragmentation heap is the default on Vista and later, so no need to do anything.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/low-fragmentation-heap

Comment: Check if the `HeapCreate(0, 0, 0)` return a NULL handle, specify `HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS` to indicate failure (for example, an out-of-memory condition) for calls to `HeapAlloc` and `HeapReAlloc` instead of returning `NULL`.

Comment: I can't reproduce. `UINT_PTR base = (UINT_PTR)HeapCreate(0, 0, 0); ULONG lfrag = 2; HeapSetInformation((HANDLE)base, HeapCompatibilityInformation, &lfrag, sizeof(lfrag));` - no crash. My guess is that the `heap->base` you're passing to `HeapSetInformation` is not the same value you received from `HeapCreate`.